# R - Confirming Data in 2 Columns

Tags: r, validation, logic

I´m trying to program the following logic in R.

```
if(there exists data in column A row A)
then(there must be data in column B row A)
```

Is there a function for this?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBHlM.png)

Expected output:

```
Some sort of text here.
FALSE
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: I have added the example @akrun

Comment: It is better to show the example using dput instead of images (as we can't test on image data).  You may check `?ifelse`

Answer (score 0):

```
dat1
    A  B
1   3 NA
2  NA  2
3  NA NA
4  NA 10
5  NA  5
6   8 NA
7  NA  8
8   6  4
9  10  1
10  1 NA

g = which(is.na(dat1),T)
replace(dat1,g[!(duplicated(g[,1],fromLast = T)|duplicated(g[,1])),],"FALSE")
       A     B
1      3 FALSE
2  FALSE     2
3   <NA>  <NA>
4  FALSE    10
5  FALSE     5
6      8 FALSE
7  FALSE     8
8      6     4
9     10     1
10     1 FALSE
```